# Changing Port for Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, team-foundation-server

I have TFS already installed on my PC which is using 8080 port. Now i installed Jenkins which again using 8080 port. I tried to change the port no. in Jenkins.xml however it errors out 'Access Denied'. I cannot even edit config.xml to disable the security. 
Please suggest how do i change the Jenkins port.

Thanks,
Alam

Comment: Can you post actual errors? i.e. not "it errors out 'Access Denied'" but the actual error message text and where you see it (e.g. command line, browser, etc).  What do you mean you cannot edit config.xml?  Also, what port did you try to change jenkins to use?

Comment: I opened config.xml and change the port no. to 8081 and when saving the file it gave me pop up with 'Access Denied' message.

Answer (score 0):

I got i working. file was readonly.